# как в redis создать unique id для новых записей?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

в laravel заношу в редис временный код, отправленный на номер телефона

```
Redis::set('sms_code', [
                'phone' => $phone,
                'code' => $code,
                'status' => 0
            ]);
```

как мне генерировать уникальный id каждой записи и получить его, чтобы потом найти запись по ключу?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте почитать про команду incr https://redis.io/commands/INCR

Вызывается команда так:

```
Redis::incr('counter');
```